# How to use this and context in other class Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a **`askMicrophonePermission`** function in `Permission.class`.
And write `Permission().askMicrophonePermission()` in `onCreate()`.

I don't known how to change ***this*** so that `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission`
and `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` can run in the 
`Permission().askMicrophonePermission()`.

Here is my code:

#### MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Permission().askMicrophonePermission()
    }
}
```

#### Permission:

```
class Permission {
    fun askMicrophonePermission(){

        val userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode = 1
        val currentMicrophonePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_________,android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        if (currentMicrophonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_______________, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use  below

For <kbd>**KOTLIN**</kbd>

- **`this`** replaced by [**`this@MainActivity`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

You should set

```
Permission().askMicrophonePermission(this@MainActivity)
```

Then Pass [**Context**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

```
 fun askMicrophonePermission(context: Context)
```

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system.

**FYI**

In a member of a class, **`this`** refers to the current object of that class.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!
Yes, I am a new learner, how to understand context? I read the document on android web, but nor really understand that!!

Comment: Nice, java to Kotlin transition is sometimes hard :)

Comment: the documents explain what Context is but they don't describe when and where to get it; only where to _use_ it.  very "null pointer"

Answer (score 3):

You can harness the power of `companion object` in Kotlin and create static methods like Java.

```
private companion object {
    fun askMicrophonePermission(context: Context) {

        val userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode = 1
        val currentMicrophonePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        if (currentMicrophonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), userMicrophonePermissionAgreeCode)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you use it like

```
ClassName.askMicrophonePermission(this@YouActivity)
```